# Fiddler AutoResponder Issue with Image

Tags: regex, fiddler

Trying to redirect all the request to the images from one server to another using fiddler auto responder see the screenshot

Requests to `regex:^http://10.45.85.22:8080/images/(.*)$`

Should redirect to `http://10.45.85.22:8088/images/$1`

[image]

But What is happening is it is redirecting to http://10.45.85.22:8088 with the request header as "text/html", which unable to fetch images from http://10.45.85.22:8088 as images need request header as "image/jpg"

Comment: What does `the request header as "text/html"` mean exactly?

Comment: @EricLaw: Not fetching even i try with the same server also when i use redirection that is the issue. able to fetch all other assets like html, json, js,css

Comment: Your question isn't phrased in a way that I can possibly answer. Consider emailing me a SAZ file showing the problem you're having using Help > Send Feedback.